# Class attribute on GridView doesn't work after button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView where you can edit the information on the row. So you can click on the row and this pop ups a box where can change something, then click on save.
But after I click on the save button and try to click on another row the pop up box doesn't show anymore. I have to completely close out of the form then go back in and click on a row. It works fine if I don't click on the save button. I click on a row, close the pop up box and click on another row. The problem is only after the save button is clicked.

GridView:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updOBSAddress" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" >
                               <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" GridLines="None" ID="GVAddresses"  OnRowDataBound="GVAddresses_RowDataBound"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="tblStatus" AllowSorting="false" >                    
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("AccountCode") %></ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Name") %></ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdateOBSAddress" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void GVAddresses_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView gv = sender as GridView;
        DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        //e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();");

        if (drv != null)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "GVAddressesRow");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "GVAddressesRow_" + drv["ID"].ToString());
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click here to Edit Address";
        }
    }
}
```

Button:

```
protected void btnUpdateOBSAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In the javascript then when the class is clicked it should show the pop up but this doesn't get called anymore after I click the button:

```
 $(".GVAddressesRow").click(function (e) {  
            ShowAddOBSAddress(this, e.pageX, e.pageY, "Edit");
            EditOBSAddress($(this).attr("ID")); 
        });
```

Comment: What do you do in save button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `UpdatePanel`. It refreshes the GridView using Ajax, and although the user does not see a Postback, the DOM is still changes and the previous bindings made with `$(".GVAddressesRow").click` are lost. That is why you have to execute it again after a UpdatePanel refresh.

You can use the `PageRequestManager` for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindPopup();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        bindPopup();
    });

    function bindPopup() {
        $(".GVAddressesRow").click(function (e) {
            ShowAddOBSAddress(this, e.pageX, e.pageY, "Edit");
            EditOBSAddress($(this).attr("ID"));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works the first time because you have added a click handler to all the rows of the gridview like this: `$(".GVAddressesRow").click`. But when you click the save button new html (rows) are returned from the server. You are not adding a handler to those new rows so they will not work.

To solve the issue you can use jquery `on` instead of `click`.  Jquery `on` will work for dynamically created html elements. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click) for more info.

```
// Bind to all items with class GVAddressesRow inside
// #whatever element, even new ones created later.
$('#whatever').on('click', '.GVAddressesRow', function() {
     /* your code here */
});
```